# Custom column adding to the matrix power bi like diff , total , avg

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a input like below

```
Name WK pirce 
AA   1   10
BB   2   20
CC   3   30
DD   4   20
AA   4   10
BB   4   20
```

I would like to calculate see the weeks in rows and last week difference & the last - past 3 wk value

so i have created a measure as below

```
   Total = SUM('Table'[Price])
```

for last week difference

```
Difference = 
var LWK=CALCULATE(MAX('Table'[WK]),all('Table'))
Var BLWK=CALCULATE(MAX('Table'[WK])-1,all('Table'))
var D1=CALCULATE([Total],'Table'[WK]=LWK)
var D2=CALCULATE([Total],'Table'[WK]=BLWK)
return
IF(ISINSCOPE('Table'[WK]),SUM('Table'[Price]),D1-D2)
```

for Avg - past 3 week difference

```
        LWK_Avg = 
var Lwk=CALCULATE(MAX('Table'[WK]),ALL('Table'))
var Ex_LWk=CALCULATE(MAX('Table'[WK])-1,ALL('Table')) // finding before last week 
var BLwk=CALCULATE(MAX('Table'[WK])-3,ALL('Table')) // finding 3 weeks before ( excluding last week)
var Avg1=CALCULATE([Total]/3,'Table'[WK]>=BLwk&& 'Table'[WK]<=Ex_LWk)
var D1=CALCULATE([Total],'Table'[WK]=Lwk)

return
IF(ISINSCOPE('Table'[WK]),BLANK(),D1-Avg1)
```

Using matrix I have achieved the below

[image]

if i add the LWK_avg i am getting the below result

[image]

I would like to get the result without measure are repeated just adding LWK_avg at the last

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using power query editor in this case will make life much easier than creating lot of measures. Please see below steps (Since its difficult to explain each step I have taken screenshot so that you can follow easily)

First Step:

1. Go to edit query/Transform data and perform below: Select the Wk column and do click on pivot column like below:

[image]

2. Replace Null values with zero

[image]

3. Create a custom column like below

[image]

4. Finally create a new column with below calculation

[image]

Hope this helps, Let me know in case of any confusions.

Comment: I have tried the above solution yes it works ... but it should change dynamically .. lets say 5th week is added .. it should take last two weeks difference and another column is Last week - past 3 weeks difference